# how to store image and other data

Tags: java, spring, rest

I need support for,I am trying to develop a **REST API** that is used to save data in `POSTGRESQL` with `hibernate`. This REST API basically saves the profile of user during registration, that has one `image` and 4 other `String` fields like name, gender,job etc. I am able to successfully save image in db.

Now my problem is to save image and other fields at same time,like API call that saves image and other string fields at once.

**Below is the code :**

```
@RequestMapping(path="/a",  method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)//
   public void Saving(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) throws Throwable
   {
       EventSpeaker sp=new EventSpeaker();
       sp.setPic(file.getBytes());

       service.savespecker(sp);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using wrapperclass, something like below:

```
                public class FormWrapper {
                private MultipartFile image;
                private String name;
                private String gender;
                }               
            @RequestMapping(path="/a",  method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)//
               public void Saving(@ModelAttribute FormWrapper input ) throws Throwable
               {
                   //write your code to process input

               }
```

Don't add any content type on front end, browser should pick it up on its own and you should create a HTML form with values to post.